# Can't put these buttons at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am having problems trying to put these buttons at the bottom rather rather than at the middle. I have searched through the internet, tried many things and still doesn't work.

[image]

Here's a snippit of my HTML Code:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class = "td"><img class = "logo" src="images/CoffeeLogo.jpg"></td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li><a class = "bt" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#coffee">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="signupform.php">Sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#extra">extra</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here's my CSS Code for the buttons:

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
float: bottom;
margin-bottom: -10;

}
li
{
float:left;

}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
height: 18px;
width:122px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#ca3838;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
font-size: 13.5pt;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color: #FF8080;
}
.table, .td, .th
{
border-collapse:collapse;
moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #888;
webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #888;
border:0px;
border-left: 10px solid white;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0;
background-color: #ca3838;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I used a table to create the layout of my website. If there is an alternative than using a table to present the layout of a website, let me know?

Comment: you should use divs and css for styling, avoid using tables for styling unless you actually have tabular data

Comment: This could be done easier (less code) with a `<div>` and the `<ul>`. Put the `ul` in a `div` and the `div` some `padding-top` to create the space above.

Comment: Ahh yes you guys are right about <div>. I have used this before, but forgot how it works. Guess it's time to hop to google once again!

Comment: @Biotox Yup, I had a look at it. Thanks for your example ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first two CSS rules to:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    float:left;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5heFE/1)**

You had been putting a margin on your `ul` with no units so that was basically being ignored, but you didn't want to do it that way anyway. Instead put top padding on the `li` elements.

Comment: @Jacob - meh, it was being ignored anyway but good catch. removed.

Comment: Hey, it worked! "padding-top:80px;" made the difference. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Wow, Jfiddle is quite goood

Answer (score 0):

If absolutely nothing is working for you, give the body a height of 1000 or something:

```
body {
height:1000px;
}
```

make a div the height of the difference between your nav bar and the body height:

```
div {
height:850px
margin:auto;
}
```

and make sure your div is on auto margin. This should push your nav bar down to the bottom.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
             padding-top:20px;
        }

        a:link, a:visited {
            display: block;
            height: 18px;
            width: 122px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color: #ca3838;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 4px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
            font-size: 13.5pt;
        }

        a:hover, a:active {
            background-color: #FF8080;
        }

        .table, .td, .th {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #888;
            webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px#888;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #888;
            border: 0px;
            border-left: 10px solid white;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #ca3838;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`float: bottom` doesn't exist in CSS.

The key to putting things on the bottom in HTML layout is to first ensure that the container reaches the bottom, then either position at the bottom with absolute positioning, or make sure that the flowing content above pushes your content down.

Here's the easiest way I know to do it, assuming you want the menu to always appear at the bottom, even before scrolling, and assuming your menu is `20px` tall.

HTML:

```
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="scrolling-content">
      <!-- Your other stuff here -->
  </div>
  <ul class="bottom-menu">
    <!-- The content of your menu -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.page-container { /* This takes up the whole window */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.scrolling-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.bottom-menu {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DON'T ever use table for website layouts.use DIVES (divisions )

HTML

```
<div id="box">


            <ul>
                <li><a class="bt" href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#coffee">Menu</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box{
    background:#000;
   height:200px;
    position:relative;
}

ul {
 position:absolute;
    bottom:0;

}
li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
   list-style-type:none;

}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
height: 18px;
width:122px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#ca3838;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
font-size: 13.5pt;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color: #FF8080;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NQyEG/)

Comment: Thanks for your example. This will benefit my knowledge. :D

Answer (score 0):

*Change on `li`:*

- remove `float` property
- add `display` as `inline-block`
- add `position` as `relative`
- add `bottom` to `-20px` or so

*Change on `ul`:*

- remove `overflow` property

**You're done!**

See it live in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noAlvaro/kp3cU/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kuroisuna/TKY4p/1/

In your CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: bottom; /* This doesn't exist */
    margin: 20px 0 4px 0;
}
li {
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

But, this will be much natural without a table: http://jsfiddle.net/kuroisuna/5heFE/2/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="logo"><img class="logo" src="images/CoffeeLogo.jpg" width="20" height="18"></li>
    <li><a class="bt" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#coffee">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#extra">Extra</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    float:left;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    display:block;
    width:122px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#ca3838;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px 4px 4px 4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:"Gill Sans MT";
    font-size: 13.5pt;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #FF8080;
}
li.logo {
    background-color:#ca3838;
    padding:24px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will be much easier to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/C2NEY/1/

CSS:

```
#header {
  background-color:#ca3838;
}
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 25px;
  width:122px;
  padding:4px;
  text-align:center;
}
#nav li:hover {
  background-color: #FF8080;
}
#nav a {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:"Gill Sans MT";
  font-size: 13.5pt;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <img class="logo" src="images/CoffeeLogo.jpg" />
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a class="bt" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#coffee">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="signupform.php">Sign up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#extra">extra</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of "margin-left:auto" write "margin-left:" and the margin value like 12Px or whatever you want, and the same for margin-top:
this will position it to its right place.